# BibLaTex custom style - header

Tags: biblatex

I am a LaTeX noob and am stuck on how to modify a `biblatex` style. I tried playing around with an existing style but I have a hard time following in which files all the sub-macros are hidden. 
My bib needs to look as follows:

> **Last1 / Last2 Year** 
>  (tab)Last1, First_initial1; Last2, First_initial2: Title. Publication, Location, Date.

I started editing an existing desing and it currently looks as follows:

> **Last1, First1 and  First2 Last2 Year** 
>  (tab)Last1, First1 and First2 Last2. Title. Publication.

Can anyone help me where I need to look in the varous bbx, cbx and def files to make my bibliography look right?

---

EDIT

```
\ProvidesFile{newstyle_bib.bbx}[\abx@bbxid $Id: standard.bbx,v 0.9a 2010/03/19 19:52:15 $] \newtoggle{bbx:isbn}
\newtoggle{bbx:url}
\newtoggle{bbx:doi}
\newtoggle{bbx:eprint}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{isbn}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:isbn}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{url}[true]{% 
  \settoggle{bbx:url}{#1}} 
\DeclareBibliographyOption{doi}[true]{%
 \settoggle{bbx:doi}{#1}} 
\DeclareBibliographyOption{eprint}[true]{% 
 \settoggle{bbx:eprint}{#1}} 
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{isbn,url,doi,eprint}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{% 
 \usebibmacro{author_head}
 \indent %
 \bf\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
 \printnames{author}% 
 \newunit\newblock
 \printfield{title}% 
 \newunit\newblock
 \printlist{publisher}%
 \newunit 
 \printlist{location}% 
 \newunit 
 \printfield{year}% 
 \finentry 
 \newline} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
 \usebibmacro{author_head}
 \indent %
 \bf\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}} 
 \printnames{author}% \newunit\newblock
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Hi Marco, would it help you if I pasted the bbx and cbx files I am using here? I got the bib working for the most part, what I still cannot figure out however, is how to filter out the last names from the entries and have them listed in boldface separated by slashes (as seen in my first post).

Comment: Do you use your own `bbx` / `cbx` file? At the moment I can't test anything.  But I think it's helpful showing the bbx and cbx modifications.

Comment: I copied your code in your original question. You can edit your question too. Please delete the other comments :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can often avoid modifying each individual bibliography driver by applying edits to the bibliography macros instead. In the standard styles the `begentry` bibiliography macro appears at the beginning of every driver. This is a good place to add the item "header".

Standard drivers typically print publishing information in the form `<location>: <publisher>`. For most entry types this order can be swapped by editing the `publisher+location+date` bibliography macro.

The rest of the problem is handled with edits to `biblatex`'s delimiter/punctuation commands and name formats. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authortitle,firstinits,terseinits]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}%
  \printtext[bold]{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printfield{year}}%
  \setunit*{\par\nobreak}
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{companion,reese,wassenberg}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you notice my message in the chat :-(

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Yeah, sorry. I've been hanging back on answering lately, but I guess I should've waited longer for this one.

Comment: I think some combinations are useful. Your way with `\setunit` is much better. I like my way with `\usebibmacro{cite}%` and `\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{author}{\usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}{}{}{}` ;-)

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thanks a bunch, the begentry works now, but the author names still do not. I get the following result:  <p> **Atkinson 1887** <br>
<space>AtkinsonAJamesJ: “Gas-Engine”. Patent US 367496 (US). Aug. 1887. <p> Any idea what could be cause this?

Comment: @L3fos I can't tell without further details. Does the example I gave work for you? If so, you're probably making unnecessary edits to the name formats.

Comment: Hi Audrey, I added your source code to my existing dissertation. The begentry worked, but the names did not. When I try to execute just the plain source you gave me, I get the error message: "Undefined control sequence. 1.26 \addbibresource". I commented out that line and replaced it with \bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}, but then LaTex responds that the citations companion, reese and wassenberg are undefined.

Comment: @L3fos Look like you're using biblatex 0.9; the current release is 2.1. The `last-first` format was introduced in 1.0. You can add its definition to your preamble: `\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
  \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}`
But you really should update. Many answers you get here will only work with newer versions (1.7+).

Comment: Hi Audrey! Many thanks go out to you, it works now! I am currently using a company computer where I cannot update to the newest version, but I will make sure to try it on my own system in the next few days with the new release as well!